# SCNNode static body with .dae causing issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, blender, scenekit

I have built a landscape model in blender, exported to .dae and added to my xcode project.

I have loaded the scene then attached the child (landscape grid mesh) to my landscapeNode, this loads perfectly.

However when I attach a static physics body to the landscspeNode my heroNode seems to crash into a invisible wall when attempting to fly above the land.

The functionality I am looking for is the obvious collision with the land I have modelled so the heroNode cannot fly through the land and is forced to move around it.

Note: I did not do any converting of the y axis in blender nor xcode just simply rotated the node 90degrees about the -x axis.

Edit: code i've attempted to add physics shape

```
landscapeNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeStatic shape:[SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithNode: [landscapeScene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"Grid" recursively:NO] options:@{SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey:SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron}]];

landscapeNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeStatic shape:[SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithNode: landscapeNode options:@{SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey:SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron}]];

landscapeNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeStatic shape:[SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry: landscapeNode.geometry options:@{SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey:SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron}]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify additional options when creating a physics body for a node, what you get is a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) encompassing that node's geometry.

Because your landscape is a static body, you can make it use a concave shape that more closely approximates the geometry. (Note that this works only for static bodies.) To do this, you'll need to:

1. Use the [`bodyWithShape:type:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsBody_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SCNPhysicsBody/bodyWithType:shape:) method to create the body, not `staticBody`.
2. For that method you need to pass an [`SCNPhysicsShape`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsShape_Class/index.html). Create one with `shapeWithGeometry:options:` or `shapeWithNode:options:`.
3. For the *options* parameter, pass a dictionary containing the key `SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey` and corresponding value `SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron`.

Comment: You didn't use a language tag in your post, so I've stuck to ObjC factory method names. If you need Swift initializer equivalents, see the linked documentation.

Comment: Perfect. Would I be right in assuming that it would be a performance gain to split the landscape up into a floor that is not flat but  I'm not worried about precise collision so only needs a bounding box and then groups of features that a convex hull would suffice. That would also allow for greater use of LoD and ability to reuse geometry... Is it possible that the increase of individual nodes in this method could decrease performance?

Comment: Generally, SceneKit's walking of the node tree to determine what to render each frame is a pretty small part of your CPU usage.  Splitting your terrain up into flat bounding-box or convex-hull floor segments (or a single `SCNFloor`) and separate obstacles is probably a performance win. As always, the best answer to performance questions is to see if it's slow already and profile the alternate solution to find out for sure.

Comment: Thanks. Trying to add the physics shape but still the hero is flying straight through the terrain. I'll edit my original post with code i've attempted

Comment: The problem was the fact I had scaled the node so the physics shape was indeed a lot smaller than the displayed geometry. I applied the scale in blender and it's working well. Is there any way to scale the physics shape so I can use scale within Xcode the way it was intended?

Comment: Just found the key "SCNPhysicsShapeScaleKey" apologies for the lazy question. I will add a full code example once I'm back at my computer