# Why is my node not falling through a plane with holes in it imported as .dae

Tags: objective-c, scenekit

I have created a plane in Blender then subdivided it so I could remove some Faces. When I import to my **SceneKit** scene, rolling objects do not fall through the holes (missing faces) but do fall over edges.

Comment: [See this answer, to change the default values used when creating a physics shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27513980/602561)

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment or edit my previous answer, I'll post another. Since concave polyhedron only works with static bodies and just a guess you want the plane with holes in it to move. You can instead move the camera around and change the gravity in the direction where the camera is currently pointing.